# How to display user name

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm using Google Firebase for my backend. I have a register form that the user fills out.

Once the process is successful, user is directed to the home page where it should say:

**"Welcome, `{user's firstName}`"**

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
const [phoneNum, setPhoneNum] = useState('');

const onSignUp = () => {
    auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(userCredentials => {
            firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set({
                        firstName,
                        lastName,
                        email,
                        phoneNum
                });
            const user = userCredentials.user;
            console.log('Registered with:', user.email);
            console.log(user.firstName);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
  };
```

When I console log `user.email` it works, however when I console log `firstName`, it logs as undefined. **When I check firebase, it has registered user with all the fields populated (firstName, lastName, phoneNum)**.

How can I retrieve the firstName of the user?

Comment: what happens if you `console.log(user)` ?

Comment: These 4 variables `firstName, lastName, email, phoneNum` are used in your code, but we don't see how they're initialized. Please edit your question to show how these variables are declared and get their value.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited the post

Comment: "When I check firebase, it has registered user with all the fields populated" Can you show us? In general, considering sharing code, log output and (it it's not textual content) screenshots of what you see, as those are much more useful (with fewer things lost in translation) than a description of those same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access information from Firebase authentication user data which is not defined there.

Refactor code as below:

```js
const onSignUp = () => {
  auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(async (userCredentials) => {
      const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users");
      const user = userCredentials.user;
      const userId = user.uid;

      // Add new user to USERS' collection

      await usersRef.doc(userId).set({
        userId,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        phoneNum,
      });

      // Fetch registered user information

      const userDoc = await usersRef.doc(userId).get();

      const regiteredUser = userDoc.data();

      console.log(
        "Registered with:",
        regiteredUser.email,
        regiteredUser.firstName,
        firstName.lastName
      );
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
};
```

Comment: When I run this code, it says 'Can't find variable: userRefs' in the console.

Comment: Check new updated solution

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: I have sent you an email for a quick question if you are able to help :)